# Spring Boot variable to lowercase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

Inside the application.yml file I have the following variable

```
spring:
  application:
    name: LOCATION-SERVICE
```

The name is in caps but I want it to become lowercase in the following variable:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1/${spring.application.name}
```

I know I can change the application name to have lowercase letters but I would rather not do that in case it messes up the rest of the app.

Is it possible to make it into lowercase in another way and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

To invoke methods, you need to use full-featured expressions, i.e. `#{...}`. Placeholders inside expressions can be written like this:

```
#{'${spring.application.name}'.toLowerCase()}
```

However, it looks like spring boot does not allow SpEL in configuration files, as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
>   expressions are not processed from application property files.

Comment: this does not work either unfortunately

Comment: you're right; looks like expressions are not allowed in files, so you'll have to find some workaround using `@Value`

Comment: I ended up changing the application name to lowercase instead, it did not provide any other errors

Answer (score 0):

As it supports Spring EL you can use:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1/${spring.application.name.toLowerCase()}
```

Read more about Spring Expression Language in the documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions

Comment: I have tried this but http requests will not work for /api/v1/LOCATION-SERVICE or /api/v1/location-service

Comment: @simon-martineli I think the `${...}` syntax is only able to dereference property names. For full-featured expressions you need to use `#{...}`:

`#{${spring.application.name}.toLowerCase()}` would be my first guess... :-/